# AES mix column stage

Tags: aes

In a PDF related to AES algorithm for mix column stage is written:

> The multiplication mentioned above is performed over a Galois Field.
>   The mathematics behind this is beyond the scope of this paper. This
>   section will instead concentrate on the implementation of the
>   multiplication which can be done quite easily with the use of the
>   following two tables in (HEX).
>   [image]

**Is there a formula (suitable for programming) to do this multiplication?**

Comment: Part of the answer (the after GF mult mart) is here on how to calculate the tables: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/18079/8050

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What they are trying to say that an effective way to multiply $a$ and $b$ in $GF(2^8)$ is to first check if either $a$ or $b$ are zero (if either are zero, the result of the multiplication is zero), and if neither are zero, then:

$$a \otimes b = E( L(a) + L(b) \bmod 255 )$$

where $E$ and $L$ are lookups in the ETable, LTable given, and the addition is over the integers (and not addition in the $GF(2^8)$ field).

There are more mathematically elegant ways of expressing it; however this is just about the most efficient way to implement it on a standard CPU.

However, this has doesn't have that much to do with AES; yes, AES does computation within $GF(2^8)$, however it never requires us to multiply two variables.

What the MixCollumn step asks for is multiplication by the fixed values 1, 2 and 3.

Now, computing $1 \otimes x$ is easy; $1 \otimes x = x$

Computing $2 \otimes x$ is only slightly more involved; because AES uses a polynomial representation of $GF(2^8)$, this can be simplified by shifting left by one, and then xor'ing the fixed value $0x1b$ if the original msbit was one; in a C-type notation, $2 \otimes x$ would be the value:

```
((x<<1) & 0xff) ^ (x & 0x80 ? 0x1b : 0x00)
```

Once we can compute $2 \otimes x$, computing $3 \otimes x$ is easy; $3 \otimes x = (2 \otimes x) \oplus (1 \otimes x) = (2 \otimes x) \oplus x$

Comment: [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) style, the C formula for $2\otimes x$ can be shortened to `x<<1^283&-(x>>7)`; adding decoration, that is `(x<<1) ^ (0x11b & (0x200-(x>>7)))`. It has the real benefit of being constant-time, when the `?` operator is often not