# How do we generate AES S-BOX?

Tags: encryption, aes, s-boxes

I am new to AES and I am too much confused about the generation of S-box in AES. I don't have any idea of $GF(2)^8$ field and how the things are happening around. Please answer this question with a example in layman language.

Comment: I voted to reopen, because I don't think it's an exact duplicate.  The 'How are the AES S-Boxes calculated' question assumes we understand inversion in $GF(2^8)$ (note, not $GF(2)^8$); this question explicitly assumes the submitter doesn't.

Comment: Related question http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18062/how-can-i-calculate-the-rijndael-sbox

Comment: I doubt that the theory of finite fields and its operations could be easily explained in layman's language. In the book "The Design of Rijndael" by J. Daemen and V. Rijmen, something general about GF and in particular concerning the AES S-Box are to be found. There are a number of textbooks on finite fields, which however mostly presume familiarity with some level of math background knowledge IMHO.