# How are Rijndael's S-Boxes generated?

Tags: aes, s-boxes, rijndael

[Wikipedia: Rijndael's Forward S-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box#Forward_S-box)

I'm writing C Code to generate S-boxes but I'm stuck.

Would you mind explaining one entry of the S-box? (say for `x = 0x2`). Here is what I got.

The inverse of $2$ in $GF(2^8)$ for polynomial $x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1 = 142$ (in decimal). Now if I apply the affine equation, it results in $86$ (`0x56`). What's wrong with my approach?

The additive constant for S-Box = `0x63`.

In case it helps and/or makes sense, [here's my C code](https://ideone.com/zJUjup).

Comment: The multiplicative inverse is wrong: $2$ translates to the polynomial $p_1 = X$. The number $142$ would be $10001110$ in binary, which translates to the polynomial $p_2 = X^7+X^3+X^2+X$. And the product $p_1p_2$  is: $p_1p_2 = X (X^7+X^3+X^2+X) = X^8+X^4+X^3+X^2$. Reducing this modulo the polynomial $q=X^8+X^4+X^3+X+1$, this is $p_1p_2 = X^2+X+1 \mod q$, which is not the neutral element.

Comment: Thanks but one thing what is the inverse of 2? I need it for a reference.

Comment: Related: [***How are the AES S-Boxes calculated?***](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10996/how-are-the-aes-s-boxes-calculated?rq=1) and [***How can I calculate the Rijndael SBox?***](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18062/how-can-i-calculate-the-rijndael-sbox?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Also related: [Multiplicative inverse in $GF(2^8)$
?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/multiplicative-inverse-in-gf28) and (more generally) [Galois fields in cryptography](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2700/galois-fields-in-cryptography). In fact, I might almost suggest the former as a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you use the modular inverse with the respect to the modulus 0x11b, which is an operation quite different from taking the inverse in the field GF(2^8).

For getting an idea what you have to do instead, take a look at [finite field arithmetic in the wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic#Rijndael.27s_finite_field).