# AES S-box and Nothing Up My Sleeve

Tags: aes, rijndael, trapdoor

Cryptographic primitives should have nothing-up-my-sleeve property to prove their designers don't have an advantage in using them versus the general public.

For example, Blowfish is using binary reprensentation of digits of π to initialize its key schedule. The Salsa20 family of ciphers use the ASCII string "expand 32-byte k" as constants in its block initialization process.

Now, my question is about widely used AES cipher. I cannot find any references to how its S-boxes were generated. Recently, it was proven that a Grasshopper block cipher S-boxes were generated using a hidden algorithm and that this made it potentially weaker.

So, does this mean AES doesn't have nothing-up-my-sleeve property? Can designers of AES have an advantage in using it?

Comment: AES sbox generated using inverse multiplicative in GF(2^8) + affine transformation

Comment: You should look for the document called "the design of rijndeal". Everything about AES' design is argumented there.

Comment: possibly related https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/17932/choice-of-multiplication-polynomial-in-rijndael-s-box-affine-mapping

Comment: might be helpful : https://mailarchive.ietf.org/arch/msg/cfrg/iGeC0IO9K0AGS_AvUHcOLMfd8Dk

Comment: Also helpful https://who.paris.inria.fr/Leo.Perrin/pi.html for more feedback of the original author re:mailarchive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, does this mean AES doesn't have nothing-up-my-sleeve property?

That is correct in a sense, the design of the s-box is formulaic. It is generated using finite field inversion, an [affine transform](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/17705/how-to-calculate-inverse-affine-transform-in-aes-from-forward-affine-transform/17931#17931), and xor of a constant (0x63). It can be described as a simple equation.

The other parts of round transformation also have a very simple description, the most complex being the [MixColumns operation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26029/how-was-the-mds-matrix-used-in-aes-chosen/26038).

The [key schedule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_key_schedule) adds a round constant which is generated simply by consecutive multiplication by 2 in a finite field.

Not using NUMS numbers allows the entire encryption operation to be described as an equation in a much more simple manner, and is easier to analyze. Rational is given for all choices of constants, although some seem.. incorrectly chosen, like the s-box constant, which causes a self-inverse mapping (see my comment on answer). A limited number of specifically chosen constants also prevents anything from being hidden in the same manner NUMS numbers do.